# How to display UIImageView.animationImages under SwiftUI on watchOS?

Tags: animation, swiftui, uiimageview, watchos

I have a watchOS app that still uses storyboard. It displays a table where each row shows `UIImageView.animationImages`.
Apple now suggests

> WatchKit storyboards are deprecated in watchOS 7.0 and later. Please
> migrate to SwiftUI and the SwiftUI Lifecycle.

However I was not able to find a way to display `animationImages` under SwiftUI on watchOS.
Under iOS I could probably use `UIViewRepresentable`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57177926/1987726), but this is not available on watchOS.

How can I display animated images under SwiftUI on watchOS?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69551879/6433023

Comment: Yes, the solution presented there solves the problem. Maybe you could write a short summary as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question?